# Translate from IPv4 to IPv6 and backwards

Tags: ip, internet

I have the following situation: Two computers, one running Debian, the other one Ubuntu. The first one is connected to the internet via an interface which somehow only allows IPv6-connections, and `ifconfig` also tells me that `eth0` only has IPv6-adresses. The latter one is connected to the interface only via an IPv4-interface (`ifconfig` only results in IPv4-adresses). Is there a way to let them communicate? I can not use `ping` resp. `ping6` to ping each other, after none of them can be addressed with the address in the other address space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the situation you've described, no you can't get them to communicate directly. You need another device somewhere that 1) both of these machines can talk to and 2) can do the IPv4-to-IPv6 translation for you.

Comment: I feared this situation, after it makes me position-dependent...

Comment: Depending on your environment, you may be able to activate the other "language" on one of those servers and do the translation there - I didn't mention that in my initial answer because you seemed to preclude it, but there's nothing at the OS level preventing this from happening.

Comment: What do you mean "to activate the other language"? I can not activate the other protocol due to interface restrictions in the network architecture (in my current positioning of the devices).

Comment: That's what I meant - and that's why I didn't mention it in the initial answer.

Comment: Then I have to set up my own translation server with fixed IP...